# Making a circle in a graph using excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to make something like this in an excel graph but I'm having some issues.
[image: What I want]

I use this to define the x and y position of every point

[image: The bold text is the formula]

But sadly I dont'get the right result.

[image: The result]

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: [`COS` and `SIN`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cos-function-0fb808a5-95d6-4553-8148-22aebdce5f05?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=xlmain11.chm60064&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)expect thge angle in Radians.  Use `=COS(RADIANS( A2/COUNT(A:A)*360))` etc

Comment: ...or use 2*pi() instead of 360.

Comment: Use more points! See my soln. below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your approach**

Using your formulation, I achieve below by allowing more points (I've used 360, as this conveniently ties in with an alternative approach below)...

[image: 360 'points']

Here is the same with just 50 points:

[image: 50 'points']

With just 4 points, incrementing by ~60 degrees around the half-circle (three times, since it starts at y=0)  to get this:

[image: 4 points]

Below I show an alternative approach with additional flexibility in being able to (explicitly) specify the radius and centre.

Screenshot below / [this](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98Fu91OfLGKhfUpzM?e=Oklsmp) refer:

x values:

```
=$E$2*COS($C7*PI()/180)+$E$3
```

y values:

```
=$E$2*SIN($C7*PI()/180)+$E$4
```

[image: Screenshot]

*Tips*

*Ensure x and y axes span same range (e.g. [-5,5], or [-10,10]), and then ensure graph itself has same width & height (otherwise graph may be distorted and appear as an oval or something).*

*courtesy S. Kuchnicki (2020), [source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8gygL-J1Bs)